# Copy some <tr> in html by js

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm need to copy some tr with inputs when onclick event is triggered, by clean JavaScript, not jQuery or something else, and generate ids for inputs. I attached my html. I'm new in js, whole what I found its copy one element. I'm be gradfull for any help.

```html
<tr id='needToCopy'>
    <tr style='height:16.5pt'>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="" class="s4">
            Label
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='height:18pt'>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="3" class="s17">
            Label1
        </td>
        <td class="s6">
            <input id="firstID"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='height:60.0pt'>
        <td></td>
        <td class="s15" colspan="3">
            label2
        </td>
        <td class="s14">
            <input id="secondID"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='height:18.0pt'>
        <td></td>
        <td class="s15" colspan="3">
            label3
        </td>
        <td class="s14">
            <input id=thirdId"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tr>
<button onclick="copy()">Press Me</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you clarify what you mean by "copy"?

Comment: The markup is incorrect, making it hard to understand what you're actually trying to achieve. Is `<tr id='needToCopy'>` supposed to be a `<table>`instead? Because you cannot have a `<tr>` inside of another `<tr>`.

Comment: I'm need to generate same tr under tr with id = 'needToCopy', but with another ids in inputs. I have table, in which I have tr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to copy the entire contents of the table, you can do it with a small bit of javascript. As mentioned in the comments, you can't have a table row inside a table row, so I'm not sure if you wanted your labels as table tds? For demo purposes I changed the surround `<tr>` to `<table>` tags. You can see the 'copy' functionality working in the snippet. I also added an id to your button.

EDIT: 2nd version is probably closer to what you're looking for (layout wise)

```js
document.getElementById('copybtn').addEventListener('click', copybtn, false);

function copy() {
  var html = $('#needToCopy').html();
  $('#needToCopy tr:last').after("<tr>" + html + "</tr>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<table id='needToCopy'>
  <tr style='height:16.5pt'>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="" class="s4">
      Label
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:18pt'>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3" class="s17">
      Label1
    </td>
    <td class="s6">
      <input id="firstID" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:60.0pt'>
    <td></td>
    <td class="s15" colspan="3">
      label2
    </td>
    <td class="s14">
      <input id="secondID" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:18.0pt'>
    <td></td>
    <td class="s15" colspan="3">
      label3
    </td>
    <td class="s14">
      <input id="thirdId" />
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>-->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Labels</h2>
<table id='needToCopy'>
  <tr style='height:18pt'>
    <td>Label 1</td>
    <td>Label 2</td>  
    <td>Label 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:60.0pt'>
    <td class="s6">
        <input id="firstID">
    </td>
    <td class="s15">
      <input id="secondID" />
    </td>
    <td class="s14">
       <input id="thirdId" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="copybtn" onclick="copy()">Press Me</button>
```

Comment: @Nikitosik I just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47115942/1675954) - I think it's just what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

cloneNode if you want to make copy of same node in html.

```
var div = document.getElementById('div_id'),
    clone = div.cloneNode(true); // true means clone all childNodes and all event handlers
clone.id = "some_id";
document.body.appendChild(clone);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple if you want to copy a  element inside

just use this code:

```
$("#IDTag").clone();
```

if you wish to prepend or append it, you can do that too by using:

```
$('#td').prependTo('#IDTag');
```

**Be sure to give a ID to your  element before you expect the results!**