# Add - remove button to increment rows

Tags: javascript, html

I'm reading this link:
[append a row to a table and increment a value with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115748/append-a-row-to-a-table-and-increment-a-value-with-javascript/77994031)

and I like as it is but I wanted to add a remove button on each row.
I was able to put the add button on each row, but how to remove the row when I click on the "remove" button?

Here is what I tried:

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  var lastRow = table.rows[rowCount - 1];
  var lastRowValue = parseInt(lastRow.cells[0].children[0].value);

  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
  }
  // Increment value of Segment by 1
  row.cells[0].children[0].value = lastRowValue + 1;

}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>item1</th>
    <th>item2</th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="dataTable" class="table">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" name="chk[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" name="chk[]"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="add" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> | <input type="button" value="delete" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Specifically what I'm not able to do is refresh the item value on the first input field when I click the remove button... and of course delete the row when I click on the remove button

Comment: Please show _your_ code with _your_ button and its HTML. If the row has an ID then it would be easy to select it with JS and remove it. Or if the button is inside the row, you could go back up the DOM via parent elements until you come to the row element, and then remove that from the DOM. P.S. How does this relate to PHP? It seems to be a JavaScript and HTML question - consider re-tagging your question to reach a more relevant audience. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. You can [edit] your question. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, SO is really more to help you with specific coding problems once you have attempted to solve the problem yourself. There are certainly ways to remove a row, consider that shopping carts pretty much all do that.

Comment: `what I'm not able to do`...why, where are you stuck exactly? There doesn't seem to be any actual attempt at implementing the feature, in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Your Code Like This add a onClick JavScript Function to delete Rows

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  var lastRow = table.rows[rowCount - 1];
  var lastRowValue = parseInt(lastRow.cells[0].children[0].value);

  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
  }
  // Increment value of Segment by 1
  row.cells[0].children[0].value = lastRowValue + 1;
}

function deleteRow(button) {
  var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>item1</th>
      <th>item2</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="dataTable" class="table">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" name="chk[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" name="chk[]"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="add" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> | <input type="button" value="delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The problem with that is that the numbering is wrong if you delete a row in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

Note I do not need to keep track of number of rows and I delegate the click

Also I fixed your invalid HTML

```js
const table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
const row = table.querySelector('tr');
const renum = () => { // renumber the content of the first cell
  let cnt = 0;
  table.querySelectorAll('td:first-child input[type=text]').forEach(input => input.value = ++cnt);
  table.querySelector('.delete').hidden = true; // hide first delete
};
table.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('[type=button]');
  if (!tgt) return
  if (tgt.matches('.add')) {
    const newRow = row.cloneNode(true);
    newRow.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').forEach(input => input.value = ""); // reset the values
    newRow.querySelector('.delete').hidden = false; // show the delete button
    table.appendChild(newRow);
  }
  else if (tgt.matches('.delete')) {
    tgt.closest('tr').remove();
  }
  renum();
})
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>item1</th>
      <th>item2</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="dataTable" class="table">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" name="chk[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" name="chk[]"></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="add" value="add"  /> | <input type="button" class="delete" value="delete" hidden /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That was an omission. I forgot to add `hidden` on the first one. If you want to also hide the `|` in front of it, you need to wrap the `| <input...` in a span or put it in a new cell and hide that instead